# Draw a sprite x number of times in GDscript

Tags: sprites, godot-4

Ok this has stumped me. In Godot 4.x, how do I programmatically (GDscript) draw a sprite x number of times (with an offset)?

[image: 5 godot icon sprites in a row]

I can manually add sprites in the editor over and over again. Only I don't want to do that or rely on add them and then switching off their respective visibility

```
var max_limit = 5
for n in range(max_limit):
    print(n)
    draw sprite at (x + 10*n,y)

... much later
max_limit -=1
```

So the above loop will draw four sprites, instead of five.

[image: same images as above with one less sprite]

Currently I've added a sprites with a number of frames and change the frame number to control the number of sprites shown. - But that really is going the long way around.

Answer (score 1):

For what you say, I take you want to avoid using multiple `Node`s for this. And in fact, we can avoid using multiple objects.

Instead we will do it in `_draw`. To begin with you need an `Node2D` or a `Control`. *In this answer I'll be working with a `Node2D`, the main change with using a `Control` is that you would also want to update its `size` or `custom_minimum_size`.*

```
extends Node2D
```

And, of course, you need the texture you want to draw.

```
extends Node2D

@export var texture:Texture2D
```

Here `@export` tells Godot to allow setting this field (class/script variable) from the Inspector.

Now we are going to override `_draw`:

```
extends Node2D


@export var texture:Texture2D


func _draw():
    pass
```

And here we draw the texture using `draw_texture`:

```
extends Node2D


@export var texture:Texture2D


func _draw():
    draw_texture(texture, Vector2.ZERO)
```

We might want the texture to update when we change it in the editor, so let us make this a tool script, and give `texture` a setter:

```
@tool
extends Node2D


@export var texture:Texture2D:
    set(mod_value):
        if texture == mod_value:
            return

        texture = mod_value
        queue_redraw()


func _draw():
    draw_texture(texture, Vector2.ZERO)
```

The setter is a method that will run every time the field is set.

Here calling `queue_redraw` notifies Godot that the `Node2D` needs to be updated, so it calls `_draw` again.

So, just to be clear, Godot is not calling `_draw` every frame. Instead it caches the result.

Ah, we might want to handle a `null` texture:

```
@tool
extends Node2D


@export var texture:Texture2D:
    set(mod_value):
        if texture == mod_value:
            return

        texture = mod_value
        queue_redraw()


func _draw():
    if texture == null:
        return

    draw_texture(texture, Vector2.ZERO)
```

Better.

Now, about the loop, let us start with what you have:

```
@tool
extends Node2D


@export var texture:Texture2D:
    set(mod_value):
        if texture == mod_value:
            return

        texture = mod_value
        queue_redraw()


func _draw():
    if texture == null:
        return

    var max_limit = 5
    for n in range(max_limit):
        draw_texture(texture, Vector2(10*n, 0.0))
```

Ok, so what happened to `x` and `y`? Nothing, it is just that our drawing is attached to the `Node2D`, so you can move the `Node2D` to position it, which is why I have `Vector2(10*n, 0.0)` instead `Vector2(x + 10*n, y)`. *And yes, you can also rotate, scale or skew the `Node2D`.*

And, of course, you want to be able to change `max_limit`, so let us make it a field:

```
@tool
extends Node2D


@export var texture:Texture2D:
    set(mod_value):
        if texture == mod_value:
            return

        texture = mod_value
        queue_redraw()

@export var max_limit := 5:
    set(mod_value):
        if max_limit == mod_value:
            return

        max_limit = mod_value
        queue_redraw()


func _draw():
    if texture == null:
        return

    for n in range(max_limit):
        draw_texture(texture, Vector2(10*n, 0.0))
```

And that's it.

---

**Addendum**

You hard-coded a - depending who you ask - magic number `10`.

Without further context, I would suggest to promote it, either to a `const` or to an `@export` field.

However, if you wanted to use the width of the texture, well:

```
func _draw():
    if texture == null:
        return

    var width := texture.get_width()
    for n in range(max_limit):
        draw_texture(texture, Vector2(width*n, 0.0))
```

And, yes, it is also possible to clip/tile the texture, or draw it scaled. For that you would use `draw_texture_rect` or `draw_texture_rect_region`, respectively.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for a comprehensive explanation. It Does work, but with the error: `E 0:00:00:0730   hud.gd:47 @ _draw(): Drawing is only allowed inside NOTIFICATION_DRAW, _draw() function or 'draw' signal.
  <C++ Error>    Condition "!drawing" is true.
  <C++ Source>   scene/main/canvas_item.cpp:706 @ draw_texture()
` at the line `draw_texture(texture, Vector2(width*n, 0.0))`

Comment: @GhoulFool I've tested the code and it works without the error. Are you calling `_draw` directly or using `draw_texture` outside of `_draw`? You are not supposed to. The error is telling you where you can draw (in `_notification` when you get `NOTIFICATION_DRAW`, in `_draw`, or a method that handles the `draw` signal). In the code I use `_draw` and use `queue_redraw()` to trigger it, I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I've figured it ouT. I was also calling HUD._draw() on main . - Which naturally is doesn't need!